# Blog Pro extension gives 404 error on 2nd page of Archive

Tags: 404, blog

This is probably a rare problem but it's for MagPleasure's Blog Pro extension and they aren't around any more to offer support.

The problem was on archive pages if you clicked on the "Older" link to take you to the second page it would give a 404 error. Other 2nd pages worked (category, search, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the app/code/local/Magpleasure/Blog/Helper/Url.php. There's a section which strips the /2 off the end of the URL but it strips all /2 so "archive/2016-01/2" becomes "archive016-1".

Find the _cleanUrl function. In there comment out (or delete) the following line of code:

```
$clean = str_replace(array(
    $this->getUrlPostfix($page),
), "", $clean);
```

Instead use the following line:

```
$search=$this->getUrlPostfix($page);
$pos = strrpos($clean, $search);

if($pos !== false){
    $clean = substr_replace($clean, "", $pos, strlen($search));
}
```

Comment: Oh and the str_lreplace function comes from the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string